Ethereal Issue Dropping Certain Power BI Semantic Model Database Through Analysis Services API
I have the following logic in c#:
PBIServer.Refresh();
List<Tabular.Database> databasesToRemove = new List<Tabular.Database>();
foreach (object item in PBIServer.Databases)
{
    if (item is Tabular.Database db && db.Name.ToLower().Contains(databaseName.ToLower()))
    {
        databasesToRemove.Add(db);
    }
}

if (databasesToRemove.Count > 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Temporary database(s) already found with name {databaseName}. Removing.");
    
    PBIServer.Disconnect();
    PBIServer.Connect(PowerBIConnectionString);

    foreach (Tabular.Database database in databasesToRemove)
    {
        try
        {
            database?.Drop();
        }
        catch (AmoException)
        {
            // database is lazy loaded and doesn't actually exist to drop
            // just exit the loop as the temp dbs SHOULD be deleted
            break;
        }
    }

    PBIServer.Disconnect();
    PBIServer.Connect(PowerBIConnectionString);
}

On a cube in my Power BI workspace I get the following error:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot delete the 'Database' object
'ABC', it needs to be part of a connected Server object.'

Just on a single cube(deletes other cubes without issue), somehow ethereal, works fine on other cubes, works fine on the same semantic model if you delete it by hand (in the Web interface for PowerBI) and rebuild it. Works fine if you rebuild that "ABC" cube, then after a day or two stops working again...
Why?
